# What happens to testosterone levels when bodybuilders are low in body fat and dyhatrated?

Tags: bodybuilding

I would like to know what happens to their testosterone levels when they are ready for competition after their body fat has gone down dramatically and are very dehydrated.

I'm tempted to think it may go down too because I know their libido goes away and, as far as I know, testosterone has a lot to do with sex drive, but I recalled this Greek bodybuilder who at the end of 2016 made a great fuss when he punched a judge to the floor with a lot of strength.

Comment: Wait what? You think sex drive goes down, but some bodybuilder punched a judge? How do these things relate?

Comment: @Alec He is obviously linking it to test levels (sex drive and being agressive).